# What is the best node process manager for Windows Server?

Tags: node.js, pm2, process-management

Our team maintains a Node-Express API in a Windows Server environment.

We've struggled to find a reliable process manager.

The Express js site lists some favored pm's, but they all seem Linux-optimized (Forever, PM2, SystemD, Strong-PM).

None of them will create a windows service to revive the process after server reboots without another module like node-windows or pm2-windows-service (based on node-windows).  Node-windows works but it requires manual intervention to kill node processes when you stop the service.

Any advice out there on best process managers for maintaining a node process in Windows?

Note: I've got another question out there where I'm trying to debug our implementation of PM2: [Why is PM2 not launching my Node process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115503/why-is-pm2-not-launching-my-node-process?noredirect=1#comment95096488_54115503)

Comment: This question has no answers as of now. Maybe I am the one who is wrong for going this approach, maybe we should be using linux?

Comment: Linux is definitely more common and practical for web application usage.

Comment: @CherryDT I know but here at my company pretty much everything is hosted on windows and my manager wants all web apps to be the same which is why i had to go this route

Answer (score 1):

For me pm2 is the best suited package.

I use it on a dozen Linux servers but also on 2/3 Windows servers.

Whether under Linux or Windows, you must install it as a service.

To do this you must:

- Install node.js on your Windows box
- Install PM2 with `npm i -g pm2`
- Install a package from npmjs that provide starting pm2 as a service like for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nick92/pm2-windows-service
- Start your PM2 tasks
- Issue a `pm2 save` command to save your pm2 configuration